# What piece is this sequence from?

Tags: identify-this-song

Can anyone tell me what piece this is from?
[image: mysterious pattern]

Comment: I recognize it but can't place it. Do you have any other context, like where or when you heard it?

Comment: I heard it in a coffee shop years ago and haven't heard it since. I had long enough to mentally transcribe it, but  never found out the artist. A proper ear-worm.

Comment: "Tubular Bells" by Mike Oldfield?

Comment: @Duston It is very reminiscent of "Tubular Bells", but which part of the three albums? If you identify it, you'd have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [*Perpetuum Mobile,* by Simon Jeffes, best known as recorded by the Penguin Café Orchestra](https://youtu.be/6E3znZoFnN8).

Comment: I got the key right too!